# SAS Proc format cntlin equivalent in Teradata

Tags: sas, format, teradata, proc

Is there an equivalent to the SAS format cntlin procedure in Teradata. I have a reference value table (code_value), which is used a lot and rather than doing many outer joins to the reference value table, I'd like to have a lookup function similar to the solution below in SAS. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
data CodeValueFormat;
    set grp.code_value (keep=code_value_id description);
    fmtname = 'fmtCodeValue';
    start = code_value_id;
    label = description;
run;

proc format cntlin=work.codevalueformat;
run;

proc sql;
    select foo_code_id format=fmtCodeValue.
    from bar;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can emulate SAS format cntlin procedure in Teradata or any other database other than using lookup tables. One way to avoid doing same joins again and again is to do index join. please look into below link to see whether this is what you want to do. https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Database_Management%2FB035-1094-160K%2Fqiq1472240587768.html%23wwID0EFK1R

One another way is to maintain a denormalized table and do joins with your incremental/daily records in your staging area and then append this records to your final table

Comment: Thanks for the info, Kiran.

I had a bit of a read through the index join documentation. Can definitely see some benefits for optimisation. I'm not sure it will achieve what I'm after though.

Essentially all I want to do is avoid joining a table 5 times if I have 5 different fields in one table that need to be joined to it.

Comment: please try to give your table structures in your  both your original and reference tables. someone can definetly suggest what is the better way to handle this. May be you need to denormalize your main table.

Comment: The fields from the original table are things like:
site_type_code_id
site_status_code_id
remoteness_code_id
location_type_code_id

These fields all need to be linked to the code_value table so I can access the description field from the code_value table. I also have many other tables that will need to be put through the same process.

This is actually being done as part of a denormalization process as we are creating a reporting layer for our client. I won't have access to change the original table but the reporting layer will be almost completely denormalized.

Comment: I have modified my answer a little bit, that is do joins on incremtal records daily and main denaormalized tables, if possible